# I can't able to create a node in my local machine

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I am using selenium grid concept to execute my developed scripts on my own machine.
I have downloaded the latest version of the selenium grid which is 4.12.1V.
I have created a hub on my machine itself and trying to create a node on my same machine,
but i have getting some error while creating a node

i have set all the drivers(chrome, firefox, MSedge and IE) on the environmental variables path and trying to access the driver but stucked on this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BtmQH.png)

Answer (score 0):

Check the compatibility of Selenium Grid, Selenium WebDriver and browser driver versions.

Make sure the environmental paths for your browser drivers are configured correctly.

Check that browser drivers are installed and that browser versions are compatible with the drivers.